# What do you call a dancing sunbeam?

Tags: expressions, idioms

What's the word or phrase for what I'll call a dancing sunbeam? Think of a prism hanging in a window. As it swings, the light it scatters moves around the walls and floor of the room. For some reason the term "light spider" comes to mind, but I can't seem to find that usage anywhere. Is there another that I'm forgetting?

Comment: *Dancing sunbeam* sounds poetic. :)

Comment: "scattered points of sunlight" would describe it in ways that would leave less ambiguity than some alternatives. You use the word 'scattered' and I'd tend to stick with it unless you wanted short hand terms to refer back to it once the context is set. "dazzling array of sunlight" , and "light glistened throughout the room" are a couple ways I could try to describe it.

Comment: How about calling it a “Sundance Kid”?

Answer (score 1):

As a child in Yorkshire, England, I called it a jack-a-dandy (or jack o'dandy), but I'm not finding much dictionary support for that usage.  [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jack-a-dandy) says it's used in New Zealand. All the other dictionaries seem to just define it as a diminutive of "dandy", a foppish man.

Comment: +1 for a splendid reply, though it's a new one on me, a Norfolk dumpling. Incidentally, when you say "Yorkshire", you do not need to add "England". Everyone knows where Yorkshire is, or should do. If there are any other Yorkshires, then the original one is identified by default of any further identification.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard a single word for that precise thing in English, but I can think of a couple that could work:

> Flare: a flaring or swaying flame or light ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/flare))
>
> Glare: a very harsh, bright, dazzling light ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/glare))

Other than that I really like "dancing sunbeam". As someone else said: it sounds poetic.

In Swedish we have the word "solkatt", (which is probably my favourite word) literally translated as "sun cat". You could always use that!

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with @loading... that 'dancing sunbeam' is very nice, if it doesn't fit with the overall feeling of the scene, perhaps you could use 'scintillating light', or something like that.